# Get Column Name

Tags: iphone, sql, objective-c, ipad, sqlite

I am working on IPhone Application and I want to integrate SQLite in my application.

I want ro get Column name which are retrieve in my sql query

For Example

```
SELECT name, phoneNo FROM contectInfo;
```

In the sql query I am getting proper data, but I want to know, How Can I get the column name that are **name**  and **phoneNo**?

Can any one Help me to find out this solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access column name in Objective C

N will be the column number.

```
const char *sqlite3_column_name(sqlite3_stmt*, int N);
```

or you can get list of column names using

```
PRAGMA table_info(table_name);
```